# Oldest Open Account in Power BI - DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Customer ID AccountNumber OpenDate  CloseDate
125         0-00156       5/13/2016 null
125         0-00457       6/17/2018 null
125         0-00213       2/1/2010  6/7/2019
```

I would like to get the oldest open account for the customer using a calculated column

Answer (score 0):

Try the measure below:

First, you need to find the oldest date in a dataset that contains only open accounts. Then just return the value for the row related to that date.

```
Customer oldest account num = 
VAR oldestAccDate = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN( Customers[OpenDate] ),
        ALLEXCEPT( Customers, Customers[CustomerId] ),
        ISBLANK( Customers[CloseDate] )
    )
VAR result = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Customers[AN] ),
        Customers[OpenDate] = oldestAccDate
    )
RETURN 
    result
```

Comment: this yields circular dependency error

Comment: and the oldestAccDate returns the oldest date regardless of the closedate

Comment: oldestAccDate return oldest date, as you requested. `ISBLANK( Customers[CloseDate] )` filtering out records where `CloseDate IS NOT NULL`.
Circular dependency  - if data in your model looks like sample data you've provided there is no way for that. There must be something different in your current data model. Check it

Comment: I wanted to get the oldest date of current account (not closed), how would you do that?

Comment: You have to calculate the min date in your dataset excluding closed accounts. That is what `oldestAccDate` represents. Copy the formula and paste it into the new measure.